# what is the result (type) of ternary operation?

Tags: c++, ternary-operator

Does the ternary operation return a copy or reference?

I checked the following code

```
vector<int> v0 = { 1, 2 };
vector<int> v1 = { 3 };

vector<int>& v = true ? v0 : v1;
v.clear(); // v0 will be cleared also
```

I think the ternary operation returns a copy of `v0`. And then pass it to `v`. Thus `v` and `v0` has different storage of data. Testing doesn't show it.

Thanks, Kerrek SB! I add a "should-not-compiled" example (Thanks WhiZTiM!) to show the point.

```
vector<int>& v = true ? v0 : vector<int>{3};
v.clear(); // v0 will not be cleared
```

Comment: You're not asking about the type, you're asking about the value category!

Comment: what is value category?

Comment: `v` is a reference - a reference to `v0`, so `v0` is what you are clearing through that reference.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The *type* of a conditional expression is the common type of the operands.

But I think you aren't actually interested in that. What matters is what the *value category* of a conditional expression is.

If both operands are, or can be converted to, lvalues of the common type, then the conditional expression is an lvalue; otherwise it is an rvalue (potentially requiring lvalue-to-rvalue conversion of one of the operands).

Comment: (There are a few more details, since the spectrum of value categories is finer than I made it sound, and you can also have a `throw` in one of the operands. But this is the gist of it.)

Comment: Here's a bit of subtle silliness. Consider `const int& f(const int& n) { return n; }`. We all know that `const int& r = f(5);` is a dangling reference. Now consider `const int& r = cond ? f(5) : f(-5);`. That's a dangling reference for the same reason. But `const int& r = cond ? 5 : f(-5);` is not, because that conditional expression is a prvalue and the lifetime of the temporary is extended.

Answer (score 3):

The rules are found [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator):
Relevant to your expression:

```
E1 ? E2 : E3
```

> 4) If E2 and E3 are [glvalues](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) of the same type and the same value
>   category, then the result has the same type and value category, and is
>   a bit-field if at least one of E2 and E3 is a bit-field.

In your case:

```
true ? v0 : v1;
```

`v0` and `v1` are [lvalues](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#lvalue) (broadly [glvalue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#glvalue)).
So the return will be an *lvalue* `v0`. Hence, your expression will be equivalent to:

```
vector<int>& v = v0;
```

---

As to your **Edit**:

```
vector<int>& v = true ? v0 : vector<int>{3};
v.clear(); // v0 will not be cleared
```

[Should **not** compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/04da00b830af2c17), because the value category of the result will be an `rvalue`, and you cannot bind a *non-const reference* to an `rvalue`

Comment: MSVC compiles. Compiler bug?

Comment: @user1899020 Yes, but Microsoft prefers to refer to that bug as a "compiler extension". Disable it, it's dangerous.

Comment: @user1899020: No, it is not a bug, it is a *compiler extension*. *Everybody* refers to it as a compiler extension, not just Microsoft. (Because it is nothing else than a plain compiler extension, obviously.) And no, it is not in any way more dangerous than the standard C++ rule of lifetime extension for temporaries tied to const references. Microsoft extension simply makes const optional.