# How does the conditional operator (?:) work in C++?

Tags: c++

I have written the code snippet below:

```
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string str = "test";
    (str == "tes") ? str.replace(0, 1, "T") : 0;
}
```

[(See here)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f5dfcf2a8eb8b76d)

Unfortunately, it causes a `logic_error`:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
what():  basic_string::_S_construct NULL not valid
```

I want to know the reason why the compiler constructs a string object?

Comment: It is an *expression*. You should use it to return a value, not as an `if` statement. Both possible **values** must be the same type.

Comment: Unfortunately, @Galik, as the expression for `std::string` takes a constructor of `const char*`, they are the **same type**, just it thinks it's constructing a string from a null pointer (which is what is throwing the error).

Comment: @Galik _@Alex_ is right. The problem you refer to would have lead to a compiler error, not a runtime failure.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh Consider to post that as an answer please. The question contains the [MCVE] (with some really minor and trivial additions), and is valid.

Comment: @Galik In case there are any doubts: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7e49d7f54dba37eb

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh Ah yes, same type or *convertible* to the same type.

Comment: @user0042 I wasn't actually trying to answer the question at that point, just making a comment about usage... :)

Comment: Hm... I can't find a good duplicate question for this.  It depends somewhat on whether this question is "how (?:) works?" or "why the compiler construct a string object?"  [perhaps this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42395118/)

Comment: Out of curiosity what did you originally expect the `0` to do? *(Oh I just discovered that `0;` is a valid statement...)*

Comment: @Alex We gave you a warm and cosy bed to answer now. Any more cushions or comforters needed Sir?

Comment: if you really want a one-liner then change it to `(str == "tes") && str.replace(0, 1, "T");`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The ternary operator effectively works like follows:

```
std::string str = "test";
std::string _;    // using _ since you don't store the variable
if (str == "tes") {
    _ = str.replace(0, 1, "T");
} else {
    _ = 0;  // this calls std::string(nullptr);
}
```

In the case above, you don't store the value, but a few conditions must be noted:

1. Both the true case and the false case must be the same type (or be convertible to the same type).
2. It still works even if the type does not have a default constructor (so it's more elaborate than the above).

The issue here is that your code expects the type to be `std::string`, based on the type in the true-case. The type in the false-case is a literal, a literal that can be considered equivalent to `NULL`, and therefore can be considered a `const char*` which is convertible to `std::string`. If you try to construct a `std::string` from a nullptr, it throws the above exception.

This is actually quite subtle, since if you use any integer literal other than 0, the compiler will throw an error:

```
#include <string>


int main()
{
    std::string s(0);           // 0 is comparable to NULL
//    std::string s1(1);        // compiler error: no constructor found
    return 0;
}
```

Be careful with implicit conversions. The null check and runtime error is quite graceful, and saved you from subtle errors or crashes (almost certainly a segfault) later on.

Comment: The type of "`_`" in your example is rather complex.  And perhaps key to this question.

Comment: Also, the fact that 0 can be implicitly converted to `NULL` and therefore be considered a pointer is mostly a relic from C that has caused many subtle bugs in the past.... Implicit conversions can be quite nasty, the error is quite a graceful way of handling such unexpected behavior.

Comment: (I'm sure you're aware) One should always strive to avoid using pointers at all in C++. I find that it's far better and quite easy to rely on null-objects or terminators, which inherit from the same base-class (or is the base class) but have only empty member functions.

Answer (score 0):

> so,i want to know the reason why the compiler construct a string object?

Because `std::string` provides an *implicit* constructor that takes a plain `const char*` expecting a `NUL` terminated c-style string.

There's a runtime assertion that there's no `nullptr` (`== 0`) passed with that constructor, hence the exception you see.

---

As a side note:

Your statement

```
(str == "tes") ? str.replace(0, 1, "T") : 0;
```

might be optimized out by a decent compiler, because it doesn't have any significant side effects.
So that exception you see might go away with builds using a different optimization level.

Comment: Note regarding "Both the true case and the false case must be the same type (or be convertible to the same type).
", the false case must be convertible to the type of the true case rather than the compiler examining both and deciding on which works best.

Comment: @Soronel, you're mistaken. (Unless I misunderstood you.) The type of (0?0:0L) is long.