# How does `decltype(true ? std::declval<T1>() : std::declval<T2>())` works?

Tags: c++, templates, decltype, declval

I saw the example code for template function max.

```
template <typename T1,
          typename T2,
          typename RT = std::decay_t<decltype(true ? std::declval<T1>()
                                                   : std::declval<T2>())>>
RT max (T1 a, T2 b) {
    return b < a ? a : b;
}
```

I know what is `decltype` and `declval`. But I couldn't understand why it uses ternary operator with always true to deduce return type.

If I use `max(1, 2.5)` it returns `double` type of `2.5`, which means `RT` is deduced to second parameter `T2` or `double`. How is it possible even though `decltype` returns only type of `T1`?

(I know I can use `auto` for return type to simplify code. But my purpose is to understand the usage of weird code.)

Comment: It can also be false, it doesn't matter. The expression result matters. The ternary operator doesn't return a type, it returns the "biggest" type of two.

Comment: There's probably a question covering this, but for you to think about: What is the type of the expression `x ? 1 : 2.5`? Not the type of the operands, but the type of the expression as a whole.

Comment: Anyway this would be bad library code IMO, it allows for implicit conversions (with all the risks of rounding issues). A good max function should only specialize on one type

Comment: Some related, but  more abstract, questions: [What is the result type of '?:' (ternary/conditional operator)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8535226) and [what is the result (type) of ternary operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42395118) *Finding an exact duplicate to your question is a challenge, given how grounded it is in a concrete example. Maybe there is no a true duplicate on the site.*

Comment: @JaMiT That's a good point. I think the type of the expression of ternary operation is the common type of both parameter. Am I correct?

Comment: Will std::common_type deliver the same type in this case?

Comment: @Klaus unless there is a specialisation of `std::common_type` for `T1` and `T2` (possibly decayed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::decay_t<decltype(true ? std::declval<T1>() : std::declval<T2>())>` is a way of obtaining the "common type" of `T1` and `T2`. Presumably, if `T1 = int` and `T2 = double`, this is intended to be `double` because `int` would be converted to `double` in an expression such as `int{...} + double{...}`.

See [What is the result type of '?:' (ternary/conditional operator)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8535226/5740428)

Note that `std::declval` returns an rvalue reference, and `std::decay_t` removes that reference qualification so that `RT` is not a reference, but an object type.

More commonly, people use `std:common_type_t` which uses the conditional operator as one of the ways of obtaining a common type.

```cpp
template <typename T, typename U, typename R = std::common_type_t<T, U>>
R max(T a, U b) {
    return b < a ? a : b;
}
```

Or alternatively:

```cpp
// C++20 abbreviated function template
// C++11 trailing return type with decltype
auto max(auto a, auto b) -> decltype(b < a ? a : b) {
    return b < a ? a : b;
}
```